# How Do You Properly Install the Transmog Mod for Azerothcore WOTLK 3.3.5?

Tags: azerothcore

I apologize in advance for the long post. As indicated by the title, I need help installing the transmog mod for Azerothcore (WOTLK 3.3.5).

**BACKGROUND**
To give some background into this issue, a week or two ago, I installed GitHub Desktop, C-Make, Visual Studio 2022, MySQL Server, and HeidiSQL to compile my own Azerothcore WOTLK 3.3.5.

I followed the steps of a certain youtube guide and got my WOTLK working through a 3.3.5 client:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6EC5CqThWY

Luckily, I was able to run and play it smoothly without issues. But then I tried installing the transmog module provided on the Azerothcore mod page. This is where I failed spectacularly.
https://www.azerothcore.org/module-submit.html#/details/74011079

**CONFUSION OF TERMS AND CONCEPTS**

Like I wrote earlier, this is my first time using Visual Studio, HeidiSQL, SQL Server, and the other software I mentioned above. I would be thankful for clarification regarding the following matters:

**1)** I do not know what a "commit" is. The author wrote that users should "use at least this AzerothCore commit" and provided a link:
https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/commit/b6cb9247ba96a862ee274c0765004e6d2e66e9e4
How would you use a "commit"

**2)** The author also instructs users, "If using this module with an AzerothCore commit older than
https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/commit/b34bc28e5b02514fca3519beac420c58faa89cad

please delete the IDs 50000 and 50001 from npc_text before upgrading AzerothCore:
"DELETE FROM `npc_text` WHERE `ID` IN (50000,50001)"

Is "npc_text" a file? Would we just access it through our usual windows File Explorer or open a subsection under our database manager to make adjustments?

**3)** I also do not understand what the author means by "Import the SQL to he right Database (auth, world, or chracters."
By "SQL" does he mean the SQL files? Where exactly and how would I import those? Do I use a drag and drop method, or do I use the import function in the database manager?

**4)** Additionally, the author also writes that users will require AzerothCore v1.0.2+. How would you check your AzerothCore version?

**5)** If there is anything else I could be missing (except actually learning how to code and program), I would be very thankful if it was pointed out.

**STEPS I TOOK**

Because of my lack of coding/programming/database knowledge, I failed to understand most of the instructions. All I understood was extracting the "mod-transmog-master" folder under "AzerothCore > modules".
Depite my lack of comphrehension, I tried to follow the instructions to the best of my ability, because I really wanted to use to transmog mod and have fun. The steps I took were...

**1)** Place the mod-transmog-master folder in the AzerothCore > modules directory as instructed.

**2)** Try to import the .sql files found under "mod-transmog-master > data > sql" under the "acore_characters" and "acore_world" sections of my database. I used HeidiSQL.

(For example, I would click on acore_characters in HeidiSQL, right click on the blank "Query" page, and select "Load SQL File..." After that, I would select "trasmorg.sql" found under "mod-transmog-master > data > sql > db-characters" and clicked "Yes" to the "Really auto-encoding?" messsagebox that appeared. I proceeded to do this to the .sql files under "mod-transmog-master > data > sql > db-world" as well)

**3)** After that, I would run C-Make. I made sure that the source code location was "C:/AzerothCore" and that the binaries output folder was "C:/Build." Then I would click Configure, Generate, then Configure and Generate again, before clicking on "Open Project" to open Visual Studio 2022.

**4)** Then, once visual studio 2022 was opened and "Ready," I would make sure that Debug was set to RelWithDebInfo instead, clean the "ALL_BUILD" section, and then selected "Build" button to compile (if compile is the right word).

**5)** At the end of the ~five minute build process, I would always get the message, "Build: 18 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped" in the end. My "authserver.exe" was always in the build > bin > RelWithDebInfo folder, but my "worldserver.exe" file kept getting deleted.

The end of the output message would always have a "**fatal error LNK1120**: 1 unresolved externals":

18>   Creating library C:/Build/src/server/apps/RelWithDebInfo/worldserver.lib and object C:/Build/src/server/apps/RelWithDebInfo/worldserver.exp

18>modules.lib(ModulesLoader.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl Addmod_transmog_masterScripts(void)" (?Addmod_transmog_masterScripts@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl AddModulesScripts(void)" (?AddModulesScripts@@YAXXZ)

18>C:\Build\bin\RelWithDebInfo\worldserver.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

18>Done building project "worldserver.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

19>------ Build started: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: RelWithDebInfo x64 ------

19>Building Custom Rule C:/AzerothCore/CMakeLists.txt
========== Build: 18 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

**6)** I then tried using a backed up "worldserver.exe" file to run the game, and then I noticed one red line in the worldserver.exe console:

"Script named 'npc_transmogrifier' is assigned in the database, but has no code!"

Shortly after, it was followed by four more red lines:

Table `command` contains data for non-existant command 'transmog'. Skipped.

Table `command` contains data for non-existant command 'transmog add'. Skipped.

Table `command` contains data for non-existant command 'transmog add set'. Skipped.

Table `command` contains data for non-existant command 'transmog sync'. Skipped.

**7)** When I logged into the game, I was able to access my characters and play surprisingly smoothly. I even managed to summon the transmog NPC using the command provided by the mod author, ".npc add 190010"

But when I tried interacting with the NPC, all it told me was the generic "Greetings" message.

This is the end of the "steps" I took.

How do I install the mod correctly?

Please excuse my lack of understanding and inability to learn quickly. I hope I can use this chance to learn more about modding my WOTLK, using stack overflow, and possibly even help others facing similar predicaments.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: in the `modules` folder, rename `mod-transmog-master` to `mod-transmog`, then rerun CMake and build in Visual Studio.

Explanation: modules are sensitive to the name of their root folder in `modules/`. When adding a module, you should use `git clone` to download the repository instead of using GitHub's download button. Not only this will name the folder properly, but you will also be able to update your modules with `git pull`, making it way easier to maintain down the line.

To answer your questions:

1. In a nutshell, a commit is a set of changes applied to the source files by a contributor. This creates a "snapshot" of the project at a point in time, materialised by the identifier you've seen, which is called a hash (`b6cb9247ba96a862ee274c0765004e6d2e66e9e4` in your case). The easiest way to make sure your local repository includes this commit is looking at the commit date. You can do this by clicking the provided GitHub link and looking at the info at the top: `Winfidonarleyan committed on Mar 25, 2019`. This is dated march 2019 so you're most likely good to go.
2. Same method as above to check if you have this commit. `npc_text` is a table inside your world database. To apply the specified adjustments if necessary, open HeidiSQL, navigate to the world database, then to the `npc_text` table, open a new query tab and run the provided queries.
3. In the `data/sql` folder of the repository, you will find `db-characters` and `db-world`. The contents of the SQL files in `db-characters` should be applied to the characters database, and the contents of the SQL files in `db-world` should be applied to the world database. You can do so with HeidiSQL by selecting the database, opening a new query tab, pasting the contents and pressing the Execute button.
4. Not entirely sure, but I suppose this is the version written [here](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/30197f40d687eae97a07d6730b6933c63f1a3983/CMakeLists.txt#L22).

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your wonderful response!

1) As you have instructed, I renamed the folder to "mod-transmog" under the modules folder of the repository "AzerothCore > modules > mod-transmog."

2) I also opened up HeidiSQL and did exactly as you have told me regarding "npc_text, "db-characters," and "db-world."

3) Also, I am not sure I was supposed to do this, but I also overwrote files in the repository's data > sql files with the corresponding data > sql files from the data folder of the "mod-transmog" folder.

It works perfectly now! I can't thank you enough.